# Exchange cannot be Autodiscovered from Sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2007, exchange-server, autodiscovery

I've created an ascx control for use in Sharepoint that accesses Exchange 2010 via it's web services. When run in it's own ASP.NET test site (wrapped in a simple aspx page) all works fine. As soon as the control is used within Sharepoint a "The Autodiscover service couldn't be located" error is encountered.

The code behind dll for the ascx control has been dropped in to the GAC and also Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll

Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll has also been added to the safe control list in web.config for the sharepoint site:

```
<SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
```

I can ping the autodiscovery service and access the Exchange web service url https://mydomain.com/EWS/Services.wsdl from the Sharepoint server.

A username and password is being sent to the service in the ascx's code behind:

```
Dim service As ExchangeService = New ExchangeService()
service.Credentials = New WebCredentials(usrExchange, pwdExchange)
service.ImpersonatedUserId = New ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, email)
```

Interestingly, if I specify the url https://mydomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx to the service I get a 405 Method not allowed error.

Anyone have any ideas what the issue might be?

Cheers,
Gavin

Comment: Cheers Pradeep will do. Didn't know about that one! :)

Comment: Interestingly this works fine from the dev box, it's just the live box that results in a 405 error. I can access https://mydomain.com/EWS/Services.wsdl from both boxes using the web browser without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem and I think I've found the solution. I had to add the domain root certificate which was used by the exchange server to the SharePoint under "Manage Trust".

After that everything worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

The ascx control could be executing the web service call as the account that is running SharePoint. That account may not have access to the Exchange web service.

Comment: The call to the service in code behind sets a specific username and password - adding extra detail to original question to show this. Thanks though :)

Comment: Yeah I would've tossed that in a comment but didn't have enough access to do so at the time.